# I can't add xbee package

Tags: xbee

I can't add xbee package to my pip `9.0.1`. I installed two python versions `2.7.13` and `3.5`
Have you any idea about the bellow error list when i write the command: `pip search xbee` ?

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 45, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 62, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 775, in request
    headers=headers, stream=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 535, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

Comment: Your PRi time is correct ?

Comment: yes, it is correct

Comment: What is your OS version please ?

Comment: i installed python on rasbian

Comment: @ElhooEltou, yes but what is your Raspbian version ?

Comment: @ElhooEltou, Please take a look [here](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-python) for the xbee python lib install and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi) for your `pip search` SSL error.

Comment: My OS version is 9

Comment: @ElhooEltou, ok, your OS is out of date. Install Buster. Else, try using `pip install digi-xbee` or download the github project and use `python setup.py install` (see my others comments for the links)

Comment: when i add the command pip install digi-xbee, i've the following error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement digi-xbee (from version:) No matching distribution found for digi-xbee

Comment: Because your OS is out of date probably. Try to download the lib on github and use `python setup.py install `. The best thing is to start by updating your version of Raspbian.

Comment: I think that my raspberry has problem with unmet dependencies. I followed the steps of https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa but it doesn't work. I have error when i type sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 1):

Update you Raspbian and try to download the github [xbee-python](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-python) project and use

`pip install digi-xbee`

or

`python setup.py install`